# The significance of the number in front of a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I believe I have solved the series to $-4/9$ however I'm not sure of the significance of the 9 in front of sigma. Is this simply multiplying the final result or is it something different?

The series in question is

$$9\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac{4}{5}\right)^n$$

Comment: I means 9 times the sum we would like to find. Multiplication like usual. Keep in mind that if the sum converges, it is one number.

Comment: Had the multiplier been $-9/4$, we could have called this operation a normalization...

Comment: So I'm correct in saying the answer is -4?

Comment: It is simply multiplying the final result. (Although it's worthwhile to note $\sum_{i=1}}^n (2x^2 +3) = \sum 2x^2 + \sum 3 = 2\sum x^2 +3\sum 1= 2(\sum x^2) +3n $ is a useful trick.) So are you correct in saying the answer is -4? Lesee $9\sum (-4/5)^n = 9*\frac 1 {1-(-4/5)}=9*5/9 =5$. Well... I may have screwed up. But yes, whatever the sum is, you just multiply by 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution of  the  series is correct. According to the formula for *[geometric power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^n=\frac{q}{1-q}\qquad\qquad |q|<1$$

we obtain 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac{4}{5}\right)^n=\frac{-\frac{4}{5}}{1+\frac{4}{5}}=-\frac{4}{9}
\end{align*}

> We  do not  explicitely need to write a multiplication sign between a  factor and a series to denote the multiplication. We can simply write $9\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac{4}{5}\right)^n$
>   and the meaning is 
>   \begin{align*}
> 9\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac{4}{5}\right)^n=9\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac{4}{5}\right)^n=9\cdot\left(-\frac{4}{9}\right)=-4
> \end{align*}